# Why are my Appengine incoming emails repeated?

Tags: google-app-engine, email

I'm having a weird problem with AppEngine. I've configured a servlet to receive and process emails. My post method is ...

```
public void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws IOException {
        try {
            processMessage(req);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        resp.setStatus(200); // whatever happens, don't encourage a retry
    }
```

`processMessage` generally works, although occasionally it fails with Deadline Exceeded.  (At some point I'll refactor my architecture to use task queues, but before I do that, I want to understand and resolve the following point.)

What I'm seeing is that my servlet is constantly receiving duplicates of my test emails. It's as though the mail delivery mechanism is perceiving delivery to have failed, and is retrying it.

I would have thought that catching any exceptions and forcing a 200 status would be sufficient to persuade the mail delivery system that the mail had been dealt with.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

Possibly related or not, scheduled tasks sometimes also appear to receive additional or duplicated servlet requests.

In the production environment AppEngine occasionally starts up additional server instances for whatever non obvious reason.  These newly started servers seem to be sent the same requests as the already running instances.  I've dismissed the symptom as being related to GAE cloud server redundancy and high availability activities that applications cannot control.

It does mean that application logic must be written to perform work in an idempotent way.  For example, upon first receipt of incoming data, add a new record, and upon second and later receipts of the same data, discard the data (or update the initially added record).  Such code needs transaction isolation, which adds delays, which calls for task queues.

Therefore I suggest adding de-duplication logic to the implementation of `processMessage`.

Comment: Thanks for this, and the de-dupe suggestion. I'll implement that. Having said that, it doesn't feel like that's the problem here. There should never be more that a single instance running (I'll add some code to log the object ID to confirm). Rather than the same request hitting multiple instances, it really feels like multiple repeat requests. Finally, one of the email messages has been rejected back to sender with "Delivery to the following recipient failed permanently:", which again suggests that the issue is that the google email-> appengine delivery mechanism believes the request failed.

Answer (score 1):

Found it.

The problem is that I was catching the soft DeadlineExceeded exception and then doing too much processing before my process was being killed with HardDeadlineExceededError